# Maya python connecting curve control to locator

Tags: python, maya

I was wondering why this is erroring out on the str? I've tried to narrow down where the problem could be and it has something to do with the variable ShapeNode? I'm not sure why though. I was hoping someone could help shed some light on this.

Thank you.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.file(new=True, f=True)

nodes = []

# create a line of nodes
for i in range(0,6):
    # create node then move it
    node = cmds.spaceLocator()
    cmds.xform(node, ws=True, t=(4*i,0, 0) )

    nodes.append(node)


# collect positions
pts = []

for n in nodes:
    p = cmds.xform(n, query=True, translation=True, worldSpace=True )
    pts.append(p)

# create curve and rename
line = cmds.curve(d=1, p=pts )
newPath = cmds.rename( line, 'Pathway_00' )

# create connections between objects and curve
count = len(pts)
for i in range(0,count):
    node = nodes[i]

    shapeNode = cmds.listRelatives(node, fullPath=True, shapes=True)
    shapeTransform = cmds.ls(newPath)[0]
    shapePath = cmds.listRelatives(shapeTransform, fullPath=False, shapes=True)

    ctrl =  (shapePath[0] + '.controlPoints[' + str(i) + ']')

    cmds.connectAttr( (shapeNode + '.worldPosition[0]'), ctrl , f=True )
```

Comment: What/where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shapeNode is a list. Change your last line by :

```
cmds.connectAttr( shapeNode[0] + '.worldPosition[0]' , ctrl , f=True )
```

or shapeNode variable set up by :

```
shapeNode = cmds.listRelatives(node, fullPath=True, shapes=True)[0]
```

hope it help.
cheers.